# jQuery Ajax wait on result MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Since the (Ajax) `async: false` is deprecated i've a problem awaiting the result from the controller.

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function () {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
  },
  url: '/ApplicationSettings/TestMuisConnection',
  type: 'GET',
}).done(function (data) {
  $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
  if (data.succes) {
    alert("Connectie geslaagd!");
  } else {
    alert("Connectie mislukt!");
  }
}).fail(function (data) {
  $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
  alert("Onverwachte fout!");
});
```

The AJAX function call's the following method in the controller:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> TestMuisConnection() {
   return Json(new { succes = await Task.Run(() => _muisAuthHelper.TestConnection()) });
 }
```

The problem is that the`.fail()` function is called before the mvc controller function has returned a value. So it doesn't wait for it's response. I've looked at many posts, but I can't figure out how to wait for the response of the controller.

Comment: `fail()` will only be called when there is some `error` in your response i-e when error code falls in the category of error codes `500`, `403` etc

Comment: check your server logs in `console` of browser for `error`

Comment: I've looked there does not appear an error in the console of the browser.

Comment: It might be sth like method not allowed, wrong parameters, etc

Comment: When I set async to false it works like a charm. But I don't get how to fix it without the async set to false.

Comment: Found the problem. My functions where correct, but the button who called the ajax function was the problem. It was in the same div as the save button. Because of that the page reloaded...